# Segmentation fault with boost spirit parser for one digit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to use Boost.Spirit.
When I test a very simple parser, which must parse only one digit, the program crash.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

auto const noneZero = qi::char_('1') |
                      qi::char_('2') |
                      qi::char_('3');

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input = "9";
    std::string output;

    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), noneZero, output))
    {
        std::cout << "Ok => '" << output << "'\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
It should be a very simple case, I can't figure out where I'm doing something wrong.

Stranger, if I write the following code all work fine...
But why?! The grammars should be the same, no?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

auto const noneZero = qi::char_('1', '9');

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input = "9";
    std::string output;

    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), noneZero, output))
    {
        std::cout << "Ok => '" << output << "'\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even more interesting, the following program does not crash:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

auto const noneZero = qi::char_('1') |
                      qi::char_('2');

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input = "9";
    std::string output;

    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), noneZero, output))
    {
        std::cout << "Ok => '" << output << "'\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Someone could explain me why this grammar does not crash:

```
auto const noneZero = qi::char_('1') |
                      qi::char_('2');
```

And why this grammar crash:

```
auto const noneZero = qi::char_('1') |
                      qi::char_('2') |
                      qi::char_('3');
```

Suspecting something wrong on my own computer, I've tried all theses examples on coliru, with the same results.
All theses examples has been compiled with the following command:

```
clang++ test.cpp -Wall -Werror -Wextra --std=c++14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using auto, without deepcopying the Proto expression trees. This creates dangling references, and hence [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Here's a fix (note the shorter way to write it, too):

```
auto const nonZero = qi::copy(qi::char_("1-3"));
```

You could also just write

```
auto const nonZero = qi::copy(qi::digit - '0');
```

All the other samples "working" is still Undefined Behaviour (UB). Anything can happen if you go outside the lines.

#### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb4bddda3e9ee91e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

auto const nonZero = qi::copy(qi::char_("1-9"));

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input = "9";
    std::string output;

    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), nonZero, output))
    {
        std::cout << "Ok => '" << output << "'\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
Ok => '9'
```